# Почему запрос работает в file_get_contents но не работает в GuzzleHttp?

Tags: php, json, guzzle

Есть api центрального банка Сингапура.

```
https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=95932927-c8bc-4e7a-b484-68a66a24edfe&limit=1&sort=end_of_day+desc
```

Если сделать запрос этого url с помощью file_get_contents то все отлично.
При этом если сделать запрос через **Guzzle 6.3.3**, то вместо json получаю html страницу с ошибкой "Страница перемещена".

```
$url = 'https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=95932927-c8bc-4e7a-b484-68a66a24edfe&limit=1&sort=end_of_day+desc';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
dd($content);
```

Собственно в чем разница между обычном file_get_contents и get запросов через Guzzle? С какими параметрами можно поиграться?

Comment: в обработке 302 заголовков ответа видимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guzzle нужно разрешить редиректы

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'allow_redirects'=>true,
]);
```

В вашем случае проблема на самом деле в другом, их api проверяет юзерагент пользователя судя по всему и все что не разрешено кидает на ошибку вот таким образом у меня получилось контент получить

```
$r = (new Guzzle(
        [
            'headers' => [
                 'User-Agent' => 
                     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
            ]
        ])
     )
    ->request('GET', "https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=95932927-c8bc-4e7a-b484-68a66a24edfe&limit=1&sort=end_of_day+desc");

    dump((string) $r->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Пробовал. Не работает  $response = $client->request('GET', $url, ['allow_redirects' => true]);

Comment: Есть мнение что проблема в чем то другом, сейчас открыл страницу в браузере, там на сколько я вижу нет редиректов

Comment: да. я тоже посмотрел он изначально 200 код выдает. дело не в редиректах

Comment: Обновил ответ, там проблема с юзерагентом а не редиректами

Comment: Спасибо. А у file_get_contents какой user agent по умолчанию? Просто интересно почему он работал?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю думаю, либо пустой, либо PHP {$ver}